# Connecting to Websphere MQ in JMS using DLL authentication

Tags: jms, ibm-mq

Our current C# application does not use a username and password to connect to `WebSphere MQ`, rather a DLL contains all the security information. If this DLL exists, C# will be able to access MQ.

When connecting from Java or Scala, how would one configure JMS so that rather than using a simple user\password, like:

```
properties.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "user")
properties.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password")
val ctx = new InitialContext(properties)
```

instead it uses the DLL?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That DLL must be containing a security exit to be used by the MQ Client.

You should specify the security exit in the SECEXIT property of the MQConnectionFactory.

More about setting up the MQ classes for JMS to use the security exit:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q032490_.htm?lang=en

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a vendor solution or something home-grown for the security exits?

- If it is a home-grown security exit then talk with the person in your company who wrote it.
- If it is a vendor solution then contact the vendor for the Java client-side security exit.  If you happen to be using [Capitalware's MQAUSX](http://www.capitalware.com/mqausx_overview.html) solution then I known there is a Java & JMS client-side security exit plus the documentation describes how to configure it.